# how to load multiple files in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How to store multiple files in mongoldb  with pymongo  commands programmatically? Does anyone have an idea? Considering that this is a very common task I wasn't able to find a solution two days now, searching through Stack Overflow  and trying my own solutions.

Say you have a folder with many .csv files, how do we import every file sequentially in a different collection in the same database?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is going to be with mongoimport, which you have noticed only does one file at a time.  I would suggest using your OS to call this program repeatedly.  Which OS are you using?

Comment: I use OSX and i run mongodb through Ipython

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with IPython.  I will have to let someone else give you an answer.